# C# regexp negative lookahead

Tags: c#, regex

i have a problem with replacing characters after specific character. For example i want to replace first  'aa' to '33' with this code.

```
 string str = "dc1aaaafg";
 string pattern = @"a{2}(?!(1))";
 Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
 string result = rgx.Replace(str, "33");
```

but the result is 'dc13333fg'. It replaced the second group after '1'. I need to replace only first group like 'dc133aafg'. How can i achive this. I have a large string and it can be many replacing, this is just example.

Comment: What do you mean "first aa"? Only first "aa" in the entire string? Or, all "aa"'s not preceded by "a"? Btw, this construct `(?!(1))` is a lookahead negastive assertion for the character '1', and its encased in a capture group. What is your intention here?

Comment: i need first 'aa' after each '1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Regex.Replace()` is global. It will replace as many times as the pattern matches<sup>*</sup>.

You could use [`Regex.Replace(String, String, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) to limit the number of operations.

```
string result = rgx.Replace(str, "33", 1);
```

Or you change the pattern to a look-behind.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=1)a{2}");
string result = rgx.Replace(str, "33");
```

---

<sup>*</sup> Note that `Replace()` is *global*, but not *incremental*.  Using the expression `a{2}` on `"aaaaaa"` to with the replacement `"ba"` will result in `"bababa"`, not in `"bbbbba"`.

Comment: Thanks! I need more than one replacement in a string so i changed pattern to a look-behind and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload to the [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) method in which you can specify the number of times. Specify 1 and it shall do only the first match.

```
string result = rgx.Replace(str, "33", 1);
```

Comment: "I have a large string and it can be many replacing."  Not the best English, but I'd think this implies that the pattern "1aa" will occur more than once.  No DV because there is ambiguity in the syntax.

Comment: @MarcL. are you suggesting that OP wishes to replace multiple occurrences of a pattern, e.g. 'aa', within a large string, but not successive occurrences (e.g. 'aaaabbbbbbaaaa' becomes '33aabbbbbb33aa')?

Comment: It was unclear, but my read (along with others who beat me to the punch) was that he wanted to replace every 'aa' that came directly after a '1', in a string that possibly contained multiple instances of said pattern.  But now re-reading, it's quite possible yours is the required solution.  We'll have to see which answer he selects!

Answer (score 0):

A regex pattern cannot express that only the first match is relevant.

Use `Regex.Match` to get the position and length of the first match. Then use `Substring` (or `Remove` followed by `Insert`) to construct a new string from the old string, that has the replacement you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a negative look behind : `(a{2})(?<!\1{2})`

```
(a{2}) # 'a' two times
(?<! # negative look behind
 \1{2} # '\1' is the captured group 'a' twice to "jump" over the captured group
)
```

Comment: I would think that since a's` are consecutive, a simple `(?<!a)a{2}` might be all thats needed.

Comment: Yes, why make it simple when it can be complicated :)